# How to return a Bitmap using onPictureTaken on Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm building an API for Android, where developers can use my class to take a picture. But, how can I return a Bitmap using onPictureTaken. Look my code, please:

This is a button on mainActivity:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // onPictureTaken does not return nothing
            // so, how can I get a bitmap from takePicture?
            Bitmap mBitmap = CameraUtils.takePicture();
        }
    });
```

And here is my class CameraUtils:

```
public class CameraUtils implements Camera.PictureCallback {

private Camera mCamera = null;
private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);

public Bitmap takePicture() {

    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open(1);

        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        params.setPictureSize(sizes.get(0).width, sizes.get(0).height);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
        mCamera.startPreview();

        Log.i("MyCamera", "before takePicture");

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, CameraUtils.this);
              }
            }, 1000);


        //how to return a bitmap from here??
        //how to wait for onPictureTaken??
        return ?????

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory
                .decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        //
        // how to return something here??
        //
        //
        // What logic I have to do?
        //

        //
        //
        // return mBitmap;
        //
}
}
```

What I have to do to get one Bitmap using my class' method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  What you do instead is update the UI in whatever way you want in onPictureTaken.  You don't return anything from it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I dont want to use the Bitmap on UI. I want to process this bitmap on other methods. For exemple:

Bitmap bitmap = CameraUtils.takePicture();
CameraUtils.rotateBitmap(bitmap, dregrees);

Is thre a way to do this?

Comment: Yes-do it all in onPictureTaken

Comment: But I have a lot of methods to manipulate the bitmap. I really need something to get a bitmap and process de image the way I want. Is there any logic, different to do it all onPictureTaken?

Comment: Yes, do our all in on picture taken. Our if you think out will take too long, launch a thread in onPictureTaken and do out there. But the entire point of a callback function is that you pot anything you want to do after the data is ready in the callback

Comment: But, the problem is that I really nead to get only the bitmap on callback. Can I use a "listener" to check if my callback is finished? Then I create one static bitmap on my class and on my callback I put  staticBitmap = bitmap;    What do do you think about it?